# Find uiObject by indirect parent in uiSelector

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

I want to navigate through some checkboxes and their belonging TextViews. I can manage to select the TextView layout of the checked box, but the other way around is not working, as there is an additional hierarchy level around the TextView.

The hierarchy is the following

```
<ListView>
   <LinearLayout>
      <RadioButton> : checked
      <RelativeLayout>
         <TextView> : ABC
         <TextView>
      </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
      <RadioButton> : unchecked
      <RelativeLayout>
         <TextView> : DEF
         <TextView>
      </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ListView>
```

If i want to click the TextViews layout of the checked radio box, the following selector is working as expected:

```
new UiSelector().className("android.widget.RadioButton").checked(true).fromParent(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.RelativeLayout));
```

When I try it the other way around, to click the radio button belonging to TextView "DEF", it is not working, as there is another hierarchy level in between and the fromParent is only referencing the other TextView in the RelativeLayout and not the RadioButton, which is needed:

```
new UiSelector().text("DEF").fromParent(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.RadioButton"));
```

Basically, I just want to click the RadioButton belonging to the TextView for a specified text. In this example I want to check the currently unchecked RadioButton for the TextView "DEF".
I want to do this by using a UiSelector to directly identify it and not to do it stepwise by calling UiObject.getParent multiple times on the TextView uiObject for navigating through the hierarchy.

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately no solution found yet.